# Error en el ciclo if

Tags: javascript

> El dreamweaver me da un error en la línea 6 y no lo encuentro, soy
>   nuevo en la programación aprecio mucho su tiempo y su ayuda.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var envia = document.getElementById(continuar);
    envia.onclick = function(){
        var mail = mail.value;
        var codigo = codigoPostal.value;
        if(var mail = "" || var codigo = ""){
        alert("Mail y código postal vacíos")
        };
        else if (mail.length<=5){
            alert ("Tu mail es muy corto")};
            else {alert("El formulario se ha llenado de forma correcta")
            window.location.href = "pago.html" }

        } 
}

</script>
```

Comment: podrias publicar todo el codigo del formulario, y utilizar el formato de codigo cuando editas mensaje (las dos llaves) porque no se puede ver bien asi.

Comment: gracias alejandro ya le puse de mejor manera

Comment: Que error te lanza?

Comment: error de sintaxis

Comment: no sera por el var?

Comment: Para comparar no es =, es ==

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay al menos estos fallos que harán que falle, para corregirlos:

- Quita el punto y coma `;` que hay después del `if` y antes del `else if` (y lo mismo entre el `else if` y el `else`).
- En lugar de asignar (`=`) en la condición, debes comparar (`==`)
- Debes declarar las variables fuera de la estructura condicional

y eso debería solucionar el problema

```
// por aquí declararías mail y codigo

if(mail == "" || codigo == ""){
    alert("Mail y código postal vacíos")
} else if (mail.length<=5){
    alert ("Tu mail es muy corto")
} else {
    alert("El formulario se ha llenado de forma correcta")
    window.location.href = "pago.html" 
}
```

Comment: @Alvarro Montero creo que declarando las variables en el `if` no le va a funcionar...

Comment: @eledgaar Tienes toda la razón.

Answer (score 9):

Por lo que veo en tu código están pasando varias cosas:

Lo primero, es que la condición está mal escrita. Cuando pones la palabra reservada `var` estás declarando una variable, por lo que en tu condición estás volviendo a declarar las dos variables e igualándolas a un `string` vacío.

```
var valor = 'mi valor'    // declaras variable
valor = 'mi nuevo valor'  // sobrescritas variable
```

Otro punto es que el operador de igualdad se expresa con `==` o con `===` en modo estricto, por lo que si quisieras comparar dos valores el modo correcto sería así:

```
if (valor1 === valor2) { ... } // Son iguales
```

Por último, tienes un punto y coma `;` después de los corchetes de cierre del `if` y antes del `else if`, esto provocará un error.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var envia = document.getElementById(continu,ar);
  envia.onclick = function(){
    // Declaras las variables
    var mail = mail.value;
    var codigo = codigoPostal.value;

    if(mail == "" || coding == ""){
      alert("Mail y código postal vacíos")
    } else if (mail.length <= 5){
      alert ("Tu mail es muy corto")
    } else {
      alert("El formulario se ha llenado de forma correcta")
      window.location.href = "pago.html" 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Gracias, acabo de darme cuenta que también faltaba esto , estoy correcto??                                  `var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var contrasena = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;`

Answer (score 4):

Creo que el error es redeclarar las variables en el IF

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){
var envia = document.getElementById(continuar);
envia.onclick = function(){
    var mail = mail.value;
    var codigo = codigoPostal.value;
   if((mail == "") || (codigo == "")){
    alert("Mail y código postal vacíos")
    }
    else if (mail.length<=5){
        alert ("Tu mail es muy corto")}
        else {alert("El formulario se ha llenado de forma correcta")
        window.location.href = "pago.html" }

    } 
}

</script>
```

Quita el VAR del if, creo que no hace falta declararlo de nuevo ahi, y para las condiciones creo que una forma de que sirva mejor es ((mail == "") || (codigo == "")) separandolos dentro de otro parentesis

Answer (score 2):

Una forma mas sencilla de hacerlo sería de la siguiente forma:

```js
   
    // Boton de envío.
    var form = document.getElementById('validate');
    // Le asignamos un Listener, donde click hace referencia al onclick que  activará la función validar.
    form.addEventListener('click', validar, false);
    // Verifica que todo este correcto.
    function validar(mail, cp) {
        mail = document.getElementById('mail');
        cp = document.getElementById('cp');
        // Verificamos los campos.
        if (mail.value === '' || cp.value === '') {
            window.alert('Campo vacio');
            return false;
        } else if (mail.length <= 5) {
            window.alert('Email muy corto');
        } else {
            window.alert('Enviado correctamente');
            // Aquí dara un error por que obviamente no existe la ruta ni el 
            // Archivo form.html, debes de introducir tu ruta.
            window.location.href = 'form.html';
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Dirección de email">
<input type="text" id="cp" name="cp" placeholder="Código postal">
<input type="button" id="validate" name="validate" value="Enviar">
```

De esta forma evitas de poner *window.onload = function(){Codigo}*.

¿Por que el *value* lo meto en el condicional en vez de declararlo arriba?

Por que a la hora de utilizar propiedades css no cree conflictos, si quiero que cuando haya un error muestre un borde de color rojo se lo asignaría en el condicional, no arriba.

Espero que te haya servido.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Gente así queda la version final ya sirviendo, saludos:

```
<script>
window.onload = function (){
//Instancias
var continuar = document.getElementById('continuar');
var mail = document.getElementById('mail');
var codigoPostal = document.getElementById('codigoPostal');
//Listeners para detectar el envio de la forma
continuar.onclick = function(){

//Recuperamos los dos valores de cada caja
var valor1 = mail.value;
var valor2 = codigoPostal.value;

//Verificamos que no esten vacios los campos
if (mail.value === '' || codigoPostal.value === '') {
            window.alert('Mail y código postal vacíos');
            return false;
        } else if (mail.length <= 5) {
            window.alert('Tu mail es muy corto');
        } else {
            alert("El formulario se ha llenado de forma correcta");
            window.location.href = "pago.html" ;
            return false;
            }
        } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cesar: Tu respuesta sería mejor si describieras brevemente cuál era el problema que tenía el código, qué fue lo que cambiaste y por qué.